# th hover not working on entire cell

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a hover over an entire cell. I would like the cell and text to change color on the hover. I have succeeded changing the text color, however the entire cell does not change color. I thought that matching the padding on the th with the th a:hover would work, but it did not. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th><a href="#">Lawn &amp; Garden</a></th>                
<th><a href="#">Hardware &amp; Tools</a></th> 
</tr>
</table>

table {
padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
border-collapse:separate; 
border-spacing:1em;
table-layout:fixed;
width: 30em;

}

table th {
padding: 20px 15px;
font-size: 1.25em;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
color:#336799;
background-color:#ECC442;
}

table th a:link{
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
color:#336799;

}

table th a:hover{
padding: 20px 15px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
color:#669ACC;
text-decoration: none;
background:#F5D671;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way to do it.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9bg4/)

**CSS**

```
table th:hover {
    background:#F5D671;
}
table th:hover a {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#669ACC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table th:hover
{
   background-color:blue;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cAL6j/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks! The whole cell is colored, however the text seems to break to another line. What am I missing? I am using chrome currently. If that matters.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25Xh3/)

css:

```
table {
padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
border-collapse:separate; 
border-spacing:1em;
table-layout:fixed;
width: 30em;

}

table th {
padding: 20px 15px;
font-size: 1.25em;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
color:#336799;
background-color:#ECC442;
}
table th a{
padding: 20px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
        display:block;
}
table th a:link{
    padding: 20px 15px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
color:#336799;

}

table th a:hover{
padding: 20px 15px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
color:#669ACC;
text-decoration: none;
background:#F5D671;
    display:block;

}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! It doesn't seem to color the whole cell on hover. Any suggestions?